# Error in sending push notification in firebase cloud functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to create a push notification with firebase cloud functions. Following is my code:

```
const admin = firebase
exports.sendNewTripNotification = functions.firestore
  .document('notifications/{notificationId}')
  .onWrite(async (event) => {
    console.log("event: ", event)
    const key = "cK0e5ZRAVRUAlx8hXHkNkXp7mj43"
    const ref = admin.database().ref(`users/${key}/deviceToken`);
    console.log("ref: ", ref)
    const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/users/${key}/deviceToken`).once('value');
    return deviceToken.then(result => {
      const token_id = result.val();
      console.log("token_id", token_id)
      const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: "Friend Request",
          body: "You just got a new friend request",
          icon: "default"
        }
      };
      console.log("payload", payload)
      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(Response => {
        console.log('this is the notification',Response)
      });
    });
  })
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a
>   non-empty string or a non-empty array.
>       at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
>       at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:88:28)

I did consult the following two links but got no help. Am I doing anything wrong here?

[Firebase Cloud Functions get data on real time database onCreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56022842/firebase-cloud-functions-get-data-on-real-time-database-oncreate)

[Firebase Cloud Functions Tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55545542/firebase-cloud-functions-tokens)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the use of async/await with `then()`, which is not recommended. The following should do the trick (untested):

```
exports.sendNewTripNotification = functions.firestore
    .document('notifications/{notificationId}')
    .onWrite(async (event) => {
        console.log("event: ", event)

        const key = "cK0e5ZRAVRUAlx8hXHkNkXp7mj43"
        const ref = admin.database().ref(`users/${key}/deviceToken`);
        console.log("ref: ", ref)

        const deviceToken = await ref.once('value');
        const token_id = deviceToken.val();

        console.log("token_id", token_id)

        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: "Friend Request",
                body: "You just got a new friend request",
                icon: "default"
            }
        };

        const messagingDevicesResponse = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload);

        console.log('this is the notification', messagingDevicesResponse)

        return null;

    })
```

Comment: I tried the same this code as well. But it is also not working

Comment: I'm getting same error that `Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a non-empty string or a non-empty array.
    at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor]`

Comment: I'm getting token_id as null in the console. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed. I was doing a silly mistake. I wasn't overwriting device token on login in another device.